# is it possible to do spring security without spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Is it possible to implement spring security without spring controller in place.

I am not sure whether this is possible because spring is plug gable as per my understanding so  when it is plug gable i should be able to do without a controller so that i don't need to change the controller when i need to use the same in to another application or vise versa.

from spring :

`People use Spring Security for many reasons, but most are drawn to the project after finding the security features of J2EE's Servlet Specification or EJB Specification lack the depth required for typical enterprise application scenarios. Whilst mentioning these standards, it's important to recognise that they are not portable at a WAR or EAR level. Therefore, if you switch server environments, it is typically a lot of work to reconfigure your application's security in the new target environment. Using Spring Security overcomes these problems, and also brings you dozens of other useful, customisable security features.`

I am not sure whether the points i have explained is true, please correct me if i am wrong.

Please provide me with supportive answers, since i am new to spring i would like to learn something concrete and basic too.

Best Regards

Comment: Hi Arun thanks for the reply, would you give some reference to support your comment if you don't mind?

Comment: Spring security does not need any controllers, it works based on servlet filters

Comment: You can search for samples like `spring security with struts`

Comment: Look at [this sample](http://jtechspace.blogspot.in/2012/07/integrating-struts2-with-spring.html) which uses struts and spring security